# Python : Iterating over a list of dictionaries gives key error even though the key exists

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list l1 and list of dictionaries l2. The keys of the dictionaries in l2 are part of the list l1, so they basically look like this

```
l1 =[1,2,3,4]
l2 =[{'1':1234},{'2':2345},{'3':4567},{'4':8976}]
```

I need to get the get the values for the keys present in l1

I am using the below snippet the code

```
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    x = j[i]
```

But it gives me the error that key is not present
KeyError: 1

Can someone please suggest what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Those are integers in `l1` and strings in `l2`. Is that intentional? Then `x = j[int(i)]`.

Comment: Hi , It doesn't work for me, it still gives the key error

Comment: Wrote that backwards. Should be `x = j[str(i)]`

Comment: Are they (two lists) are always in the same corresponding ordering?  If not, then you should think about again...